# Wicket CheckBox (Model problem)

Tags: java, wicket

How can I make wicket to call CheckBox setObject every time form is submitted?

new CheckBox("booox", new IModel(){
..
..
..
});

Now it's called only IF value has changed. Please?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need this? If you are calling business logic in setter it's not very good approach. If you just need dynamic model updating, go for (Compound)PropertyModel.

Answer (score 0):

What's the use case?

Surely anything that needs to be aware of the checkbox model changing on form submit should look at the model value in the relevant onSubmit()?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a CompoundPropertyModel to your panel/page, wicket will update the checkbox automatically if a form submit takes place. No need for manually calling the setObject function.

```
private IModel<Boolean> boooxModel;
...
public SamplePage(){
 boooxModel = new CompoundPropertyModel(new Boolean());
}
...
new CheckBox("booox", boooxModel);
```

make sure your booox is added to the form you are submitting.